# Eliminating vertical space inserted by a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

The following code instructs `TeX` to typeset two problems for a test. The `TikZ` picture associated with the second problem extends above the wording of the problem. This makes an unseemly amount of vertical spacing between the problems. How do I eliminate this extra spacing?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{3.) }Express the following numbers as decimals.
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$\dfrac{3}{4}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\> \textbf{b.) }$\dfrac{3}{40}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\> \textbf{c.) }$\dfrac{3}{80}$ 
\end{tabbing}
\medskip

\noindent \begin{minipage}{4in}
\vskip0pt
\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{5.) }The area enclosed by the following polygon is 63. \\
What is its perimeter?}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{-1.5cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]

%The vertices of a polygon are located. One side has length 12, and two adjacent sides
%are perpendicular to it and have lengths 4 and 10. (The figure is magnified by 3/8.)
%
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (4.5,3.75);
\coordinate (D) at (2.625,1.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,1.5);
%
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


%The lengths of some of the line segments are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!0.15cm!90:(A)$)$){12};

\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($($(A)!0.15cm!90:(E)$)!0.5!($(E)!0.15cm!-90:(A)$)$){4};

\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at($($(D)!0.15cm!-90:(E)$)!0.5!($(E)!0.15cm!90:(D)$)$){7};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U_1) at ($(A)!3mm!45:(B)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(A)!(U_1)!(B)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(A)!(U_1)!(E)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at B.
\coordinate (U_2) at ($(B)!3mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U_2) -- ($(B)!(U_2)!(A)$);
\draw (U_2) -- ($(B)!(U_2)!(C)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U_3) at ($(E)!3mm!-45:(D)$);
\draw (U_3) -- ($(E)!(U_3)!(D)$);
\draw (U_3) -- ($(E)!(U_3)!(A)$);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you are inserting `\medskip` at that point so you could just not do that, or to close it up more just change `\medskip` to `\vspace{-20pt}` or whatever you want, but TeX can not check if that causes over-printing, it is up to you to check that the lines in the first question are short, creating space on the right.

Comment: I can manually make sure that the words from the first problem are not typeset over the sides of the polygon in the second problem. Can I make the top two sides of the polygon "invisible" to `TeX` so that I can keep the vertical spacing of `\medskip` between the words in the two problems? I have that same spacing between every other pair of problems on this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a much simpler code with `enumerate`. You can set the lengths of the lines in the environment using the key `rightmargin=`. The problem with `tikzpicture` is solved with a `\raisebox` with the optional arguments set to 0pt to fool LaTeX and make it believe the figure has no height nor depth.

I suppose this is want you want:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label =\arabic*.), wide = 0pt, font = \bfseries, itemsep=1.5ex, rightmargin =\dimexpr\linewidth-4in]
\item Express the following numbers as decimals.
\begin{enumerate}[label =\alph*.), wide=0pt, labelindent=3em, itemsep =1.5ex, font = \bfseries]
\item $\dfrac{3}{4}$
\item $\dfrac{3}{40}$
\item $\dfrac{3}{80}$
\end{enumerate}

\item The area enclosed by the following polygon is 63. \\
What is its perimeter?
\hfill\rlap{\raisebox{8ex}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
%The vertices of a polygon are located. One side has length 12, and two adjacent sides
%are perpendicular to it and have lengths 4 and 10. (The figure is magnified by 3/8.)
%
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (4.5,3.75);
\coordinate (D) at (2.625,1.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,1.5);
%
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;
%
%The lengths of some of the line segments are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!0.15cm!90:(A)$)$){12};
%
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($($(A)!0.15cm!90:(E)$)!0.5!($(E)!0.15cm!-90:(A)$)$){4};
%
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at($($(D)!0.15cm!-90:(E)$)!0.5!($(E)!0.15cm!90:(D)$)$){7};
%
%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U_1) at ($(A)!3mm!45:(B)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(A)!(U_1)!(B)$);
\draw (U_1) -- ($(A)!(U_1)!(E)$);
%A right-angle mark is drawn at B.
\coordinate (U_2) at ($(B)!3mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (U_2) -- ($(B)!(U_2)!(A)$);
\draw (U_2) -- ($(B)!(U_2)!(C)$);
%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U_3) at ($(E)!3mm!-45:(D)$);
\draw (U_3) -- ($(E)!(U_3)!(D)$);
\draw (U_3) -- ($(E)!(U_3)!(A)$);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\item What are the lengths of the two other sides?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You used the `\raisebox` command with no height. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to use the option `[b]` with the `minipage` environment and [baseline=(A)] with the `tikzpicture` environment. With this code, the bottom side of the polygon is flush with the second line of the problem.

Comment: I understand. My solution requires a manual adjustment. I managed to have the small vertical side centered w.r.t. the text of the question.